# How to put 2 class selector in a single paragraph using internal style sheet

Tags: html, css

These two lines are in one paragraph. The job title is bold and the font is Arial.
The colour is #B22222. The company is italic, Arial Narrow and the colour is #00008B.

I don't know how to put 3 class selector in a single paragraph.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

    <title>Job Vacancy</title>
</head>

    <style type="text/css">
        .h1 {
            color:#ffffff;
            background-color:#20B2AA;
            text-align:center;
            }

        .p{
            font-type:arial;
            color:#B22222;
            weight:bold;
            }

        p.p{
            weight:italic;
            font-type:arial narrow;
            color:#00008B;
            }

        pp.p{
            color:#000000;
            font-type:arial narrow;
            }
    </style>
<body>

    <h1 class="h1">JOBS DATABASE</h1>
    <h2><u>Job Listings</h2></u>
    <p class="p">PHP Programmer<br/>OrangePro Solutions Sdn.Bhd.-- Midvalley, Kuala Lumpur</p> <!--should I put another class="p.p" in between <br/> and OrangePro?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually use a span for this situation.

```
 <p class="p"><span class="job_title">PHP Programmer</span>
 <br/>OrangePro Solutions Sdn.Bhd.-- Midvalley, Kuala Lumpur</p>
```

CSS

```
 span.job_title {
    color: orange; //or whatever
 }
```

But since you have a linebreak anyway, you could just split into two paragraphs with different classes.

```
 <p class="job_title">PHP Programmer</p>
 <p class="company_name">OrangePro Solutions Sdn.Bhd.-- Midvalley, Kuala Lumpur</p>
```

CSS:

```
 p.job_title {
   font-weight: bold; //etc..
 }

 p.company_name {
   color: #B22222;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

use class for each lines

```
<h1 class="h1">JOBS DATABASE</h1>
    <h2><u>Job Listings</h2></u>
    <p class="p"><div class="div1">PHP Programmer</div><div class="div2">OrangePro Solutions Sdn.Bhd.-- Midvalley, Kuala Lumpur<div></p> <!--should I put another class="p.p" in between <br/> and OrangePro?>




.p{
            font-type:arial;
            color:#B22222;
            weight:bold;
            }

        div1{
            weight:italic;
            font-type:arial narrow;
            color:#00008B;
            }

        div2{
            color:#000000;
            font-type:arial narrow;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption the postings are dynamically fed (e.g. from a DB),one way of doing this is to arrange your items into specific sections of content for each posting, e.g:

```
<div class='posting'>
    <h1>PHP Programmer</h1>
    <h2>OrangePro Solutions Sdn.Bhd.--</h2>
    Job info.....    
</div>
```

You can then just apply targetted CSS to the `posting` class. Note that this also uses the correct elements for their purposes- two headings contained within a segregated division of content on the page.

Sample **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/WhbvZ/)**

Answer (score 0):

First at all you need to understand the selectors you're using :

> .p ---- Select all elements with class="p"
>
> p.p --- Select all p (paragraph elements) with class="p"
>
> pp.p --- Select all "pp" tags with class="p" . *This is invalid because there isn't exist any tag like this*.

What you need here is the use of `span` wrapp the job title in a span with different class:

```
<p class="p">
  <span class="title">PHP Programmer</span><br/>
  OrangePro Solutions Sdn.Bhd.-- Midvalley, Kuala Lumpur
</p>
```

And the CSS can look like this :

```
p.p {
 font-style:italic;
 color:#00008B;
}

p.p .title{
  color:#B22222;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-style:normal;
}
```

The demo **http://jsfiddle.net/LS8nK/**